# Search results not updating with autocompletion

Tags: ios, swift, autocomplete, ios8, uisearchbar

I'm building an app in swift requiring to be able to search cities and I would like the search to work with autocompletion.

So I started by creating a view controller in a xib containing a UISearch bar with its associated controller. The class I wrote for the view controller is the following :

```
import UIKit

class LocationViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate {

    // MARK: - Properties

    var dirty: Bool = false
    var loading: Bool = false
    var suggestions: Array<String> = [] {
        didSet {
            searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Initialization

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        searchDisplayController?.searchBar.placeholder = "Ville ou adresse"
    }

    // MARK: - UISearchBarDelegate

    func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        if countElements(searchText) > 0 {
            if (loading) {
                dirty = true
            } else {
                loadSearchSuggestions()
            }
        }
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        suggestions = []
    }

    // MARK: - Search backend

    func loadSearchSuggestions() {

        loading = true

        var query = searchDisplayController?.searchBar.text
        var urlEncode = query!.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())!
        var urlString = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=MYAPIKEY&components=country:FR&input=\(urlEncode)"

        var request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString)!)
        var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

            if (error != nil) {
                self.loading = false
                println(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            var err: NSError?

            var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as Dictionary<String,AnyObject>

            var predictions = jsonResult["predictions"] as Array<AnyObject>

            var currentSug: Array<String> = []

            for prediction in predictions {
                var predDict = prediction  as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

                var adress = predDict["description"] as String

                currentSug.append(adress)

            }

            if err != nil {
                println("JSON Error in search \(err!.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            self.suggestions = currentSug

            if self.dirty {
                self.dirty = false
                self.loadSearchSuggestions()
            }

            self.loading = false
        })

        task.resume()
    }

    // MARK: - UITableViewDataSource

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cellIdentifier = "suggestCell"

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as UITableViewCell?

        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
        }

        if suggestions.count > 0 {
            cell!.textLabel!.text = suggestions[indexPath.row]
        }

        return cell!
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return suggestions.count
    }
}
```

Everything works fine until one point. When I write a letter in my search box, the request works and I get a result that is stored into my suggestions var.

The only problem is: the table view containing the results isn't reloading as it should (as specified in the didSet from the suggestions var). Except if I try scrolling the empty list.

Now if I type a second character, my table view shows the results from when only one character was typed. If I try scrolling then I get the right results.

Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer my question. I might have done mistakes in my code as I'm still pretty new to swift and to programming in general.

Comment: I don't see where you're calling `tableView.reloadData()`.

Comment: In the didSet of the suggestions array. So each time the array is updated it should reload the table

var suggestions: Array<String> = [] {
        didSet {
            searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simple enough for me not to see it !

The query to the Google API is done asynchronously, the updating of the UI needs on the other hand to be done synchronously.

Here is the missing piece of code, just after `self.loading = false` in `LoadSearchSuggestions` :

```
self.loading = false

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView.reloadData()
})
```

And that does the trick, hope it helps someone !